# Application deployment using MDT with no access to network.

Tags: mdt, mdt-2013

Is it possible to install ONLY software using MDT via USB? I don't want to deploy OS as don't want to lose the licence. I would like to achieve this scenario:

Laptop with installed Windows 8.1
USB stick with MDT on it is plugged in
I run silent deployment of software using the wizard.

Other bits to clarify:

- I don't want to run MDT connected to network
- I don't want to install OS from scratches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this and ignore the OS part.
http://www.vkernel.ro/blog/creating-an-offline-mdt-deployment-media

Comment: Your Welcome! Glad I could be of service!

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, you need the offline media (not the boot media). The process is explained in the step by step guide for [Deploying Windows 8.1 from a USB Stick](http://technet.microsoft.com/windows/dn481547).